# IOS development with React Native Display Zoomed issue

Tags: ios, react-native

If a user has their option on their phone set to Zoomed, the text in the app I am developing is actually really zoomed out. (Settings > Display & Brightness > View)

Is there an option in xcode or within my own code that will fix this zoom issue. Maybe disable the zoom view in the app if the user has the option Display Zoom set to Zoomed on their phone.

Standard View:

[image]

Settings:

[image]

Zoomed setting on:

[image]

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Great question! Just ran into this issue myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply:

```
allowFontScaling={false}
```

To prevent this.

So, you can implement it like this:

```
<Text allowFontScaling={false}>Do not want font to scale</Text>
```

Comment: that makes sense for font. do you know how (and if possible) to disable the screen zoom?

Comment: also if we generally want to send another message this is not enough.

Comment: any update on it

Comment: it's not solving the zoomed issue ,it's only not allowing the text to scan how it will restrict views, button to scal?